# How to get attribute value from xml in android/Java

Tags: java, android, xml, dom

I have xml in this format

```
  String xml = "<contact xmlns='com:your:ext:namespace'><phonenumber1>12345675</phonenumber1>           <phonenumber2>56738903</phonenumber2></contact>";

   Document doc = null;
            try {
                InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes("utf-8"));
                doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(in);
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SAXException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        System.out.println("Root element " + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

        NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("*");
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
        // Get element
        Element element = (Element) nodeList.item(i);
        //System.out.println(element.getNodeName());

        Node nNode = nodeList.item(i);

        if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

            Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

            System.out.println("attribute tags: " + eElement.getTagName());
        }
```

}

i am using above code to get attaribute values.
    getting attribute names 
    but fails in getting attribute values
please help me i am struct here

thanks in advance

NareshRavva

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your xml none of the elements have attribute `"Name"` so it cannot return you one.

Judging by the end of your code, you probably want to use getTagName() method, to get element name instead (`phonenumber1`) is the tag name not its attibute.

Your

```
NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("*");
```

already contains the elements of phonenumber1, ... you can recognize them as phone tags by for example:

```
Element elm = (Elemetn) nNode;
if (elm.getTagName().startsWith("phone"))
   phone = elm.getTextContent();
```

Comment: Root element contact
contact
attribute tags: 
phonenumber1
attribute tags: 
phonenumber2   i am getting o/p like this if run this in simple java class u got my problem.

Comment: phonenumber1, and phonenumber1 are not attribute, they are child elements, they are tags. They are not returnde by getAttribute method

Comment: ok Thanq what i have to do for getting phonenumber1 and phonenumber2 ....etc values

Comment: nodeList.item(i).getChildNodes().item(0).getTextContent(); can i use this

Comment: they are already in your nodeList if you use *, yes the getTextContent will return phonenumber value, see the update.